# Do I have to install Ruby on my Apache server to run scripts

Tags: ruby, apache, webserver

I just have my script on my notebook. So is it necessary to install ruby on apache webserver to run it or are there other possibilities?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably run the script on your notebook directly.

Try creating an example script like this:

```
echo "puts 'hello'" > example.rb
ruby example.rb
```

That should print:

```
hello
```

You can run any Ruby code that way.

You can also make the script executable.

Edit example.rb so it reads like this:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
 puts 'hello'
```

Then on the command line, make the script executable:

```
 chmod +x example.rb
```

Then run it:

```
 ./example.rb
```

If you are building something more like a Rails app, and you want to run it on a remote webserver that runs Apache:

1. On the remote webserver, you must install Ruby. I personally like [`ruby-install`](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) better than `rbenv` and `rvm`.
2. Install a web application server. I personally like [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/install_gem) for Apache.
3. Configure Apache. The Passenger gem will tell you how to do this.
4. Restart Apache.

Comment: Sorry... My script works on my notebook. And I know how to run it. I have to run it on apache webserver and asked for those possibilities... There isn't ruby installed.